# Fix the debian default version to wheezy

Tags: linux, apt, debian

I followed this tutorial http://kemitix.postach.io/install-viber-on-debian-wheezy to install viber on debian wheezy 7.6. My problem is about the part that says:

> Fix the default version to wheezy. Add this line to
>   /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10release: APT::Default-Release "wheezy";

i went to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ but there wasn't a 10release file, so i created it and i add the line.

After this i did an update and i install libc6 from the testing repository. I saw from the installation log of libc6 that a lot of system libs,etc were changed.

1. So why the 10release file didn't exist? do i need to add the
   `APT::Default-Release "wheezy";` line somewhere else too?
2. What exactly happed by installing this lib from testing repository?
3. Will i get updates from the testing repo? Did the testing entry to
   the sources.list changed my debian version?
4. How can i ensure that my default version is wheezy and i won't get
   updates from testing repo?

Comment: libc of viber is upper than `main repo (wheezy)` , it's related to your repo.  if you use `testing` or `unstable(sid)` , you don't need to upgrade of libc.

Comment: i am using wheezy and the libc6 version is 2.13. the viber is compiled against 2.14, so i did the upgrade and know i want to downgrade to the wheezy version because newer versions of libc6 are unstable for wheezy. that's why i asked the question

Comment: my friend has same experience and then downgrade his libc, i suggest you if that is your desktop , upgrade all of everything you have.

Comment: "After this i did an update and i install libc6 from the testing repository". Eek! Why did you do that? BAD IDEA.

Comment: i got the same problem , just remove "wheezy" from the text file.That's works for me dude